# mysql num rows is failing

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pass='".sha1($_POST['mainloginpass'])."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
```

it says that "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query` normally returns a resource, but according to [the docs](http://php.net/mysql_query):
*mysql_query() will return FALSE on error and also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.*

You may want to try something like this:

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

To see what the problem is.